# Is there an equivalent of ActiveRecord's find(:include) in Elixir/SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, ruby, activerecord, python-elixir

I had been using ActiveRecord previously and it allowed to load all associations of an object using an optional :include argument to its dynamic finders. I have recently started using Elixir for a python project and am unable to find any documentation that'd suggest if it's possible to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain SQLAlchemy (without Elixir): http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/loading.html

I assume you can configure the loading strategies using Elixir as well, but I have never used it.

EDIT 1:

According to the [Elixir documentation](http://elixir.ematia.de/apidocs/elixir.relationships.html), options to the relationship constructs (for instance `ManyToOne`) can include options that are passed directly to the SQLAlchemy `relation` (`relationship` if version >= 0.6) function. That means you can specify the `lazy` option to control the loading for associated objects.

I assume that Elixir's `query` method is a thin wrapper around SQLAlchemy's. In that case, you can also control lazy/eager loading for individual queries. See [the documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/loading.html).

EDIT 2:

Have you considered using [`sqlalchemy.ext.declarative`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#creating-table-class-and-mapper-all-at-once-declaratively) instead of Elixir?

Comment: Your first suggestion to use the lazy option to control the loading worked for me. I'll look into the second one as well.